# Last checkbox checked not saving to table

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

Recently I have inherited an Access 2010 database with a front end linked to an access back end on a network drive. I've discovered an issue with one of the forms that contain a varying number of check boxes, depending upon the category selected in a drop down.

It is a very simple, continuous form with three fields sourced from a table which contains all possible escalation reasons. When the form first opens it displays all 93 reasons which can be selected as is. The category drop down allows the user to refine the number of reasons presented.

Multiple reasons can be selected up to all 93 of them. The check box is linked directly back to the field "Selected" in the table. There is no code behind for this process.

The issue is this: Regardless the number of check boxes checked the final one selected does not register in the table. If I select one it does not reflect in the table. It doesn't matter if it is the first reason, the tenth or the 93.

If I were to select the first and tenth box only the first would appear in the table. If I were to select the first, tenth and 20th then only the first and tenth will reflect in the table.

Just to add another wrinkle into the proceedings, if I were to select the first, 30th and 20th entries it will be the 20th that does not reflect in the table. Only the first and 30th.

Has anyone come across this issue before. If so, were you able to resolve it.

Comment: By default, a record is saved when you move to another. So, as you describe it - with no code (or macro) behind - it cannot happen ...

Comment: If you click elsewhere on the Form and cause that Checkbox to lose focus, what happens?

Comment: Thank you Gustav and Mark C. Not sure why I had such a brain lock on this one. I added DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord in the on click property for the check box and that did the trick!